# How is というなら different from なら?

Tags: grammar

[image]

いい!? これからもし私たちが空へ行くというのなら....

Is there any difference if I replaced it with なら?
If there isn't, is there a sentence where it wouldn't be interchangeable?

Comment: I think it goes with って事なの!! at the end. The structure is X**という**のならY**という**事なの

Answer (score 3):

Actually, all 行くなら / 行くというなら / 行くのなら / 行くというのなら are grammatically possible here. I mean, grammatically allowed but each has its own meaning.

- ～行くなら: *if we (will / are going to) go...*
  Yes, this is very straightforward. The non-past form tends to mean near future.
- ～行くというなら: *under the condition that we go... / if you insist we go...*
  `V というなら` is, in most cases, an idiom that means either of the following:

  1. "[an expression that tells it is okay/allowed] ... only if V"
  2. "if somebody insists to V"

  However, neither of them fits well in this context.
- ～行くのなら: *if (there is) the fact that we go... / if the one (where) we go...*
  の is a general nominalizer, accepting roughly two types of interpretation:

  1. apposition: "the fact of [predicate]"
  2. relative: "something or somebody that [predicate] / that is [predicate]-ed / with/to/from... which [predicate]"

  And if we take the former understanding, it yields the convoluted first translation above; but it is in turn, from a learner's perspective, combination of `行く + のだ + [conditional]`, which can be practically translated as "if we are bound/decided to go..."
- ～行くというのなら: *if (there is) the fact that we say we go...*
  The translation is even more enigmatic now :P, but here the point is that the extra という works in two ways. Firstly, it can eliminate the "relative" reading from bare `V のなら` to unambiguously mean the nominalization of the action. Secondly, it adds a little flavor of quotation という, which effectively introduces the nuance of **subjunctive mood** i.e. mentioning a hypothetical situation.

In conclusion, a cleaner answer would be like:

> もし私達が空へ行くなら
> *if we go up into the sky*

versus

> もし私達が空へ行くというのなら
> *if we **are supposed to** go up into the sky*
> or
> ***in the event that** we go up into the sky*

Comment: thanks, but what do you actually mean that neither of those fit the context?

Comment: @sieman I meant that I don't feel they sound very natural to be used there either way.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to replace nami's sentence of 行くというのなら with 行くなら, the meaning is not changed much. Both 普通形(i.e. common type)（の）なら and 普通形なら can be used to give suggestion/advice.

But in my experience, the first one is often used to express a rather strong attitude, i.e. firm advice.